# Jave enum member

Tags: java, enums, scope

I am a newbie in Java. With this code:

```
public class MyClass{
   enum State {STATE1, STATE2, STATE3}
   State curState;
   ...
   public MyClass(){
      curState=STATE1;
   }
}
```

I get error

> STATE1 cannot be resolved to variable

If I chage STATE1 to State.STATE1 everything works, but I don't want to write enum name every time! I don't understand why I have to. enum is declared in the MyClass scope.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possible solution is to use a static import. For instance if all the above is in the pkg package, then:

```
package pkg;

import static pkg.MyClass.State.*;

public class MyClass {
    enum State {
        STATE1, STATE2, STATE3
    }

    State curState;

    // ...
    public MyClass() {
        curState = STATE1;
    }
}
```

As per the [Static Import Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html):

> The static import construct allows unqualified access to static members without inheriting from the type containing the static members. Instead, the program imports the members, either individually or en masse.